# android text not visible

Tags: android, user-interface

I am sending some information from my application to server and waiting for the response. Before i send i set my textview for message to display "processing request" and after getting response i display a different message.

This processing message is not getting displayed. Is it beacuse the UI is getting blocked due to other operation.
How to handle this. Threading is not giving correct result as need to display the response.
SO that involve UI in the thread .

```
 package com.PandG.app.android.activities;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.PandG.app.android.R;
import com.PandG.app.android.dataAccess.SettingsDBAccess;
import com.PandG.app.android.entity.Job;
import com.PandG.app.android.entity.Settings;
import com.PandG.app.android.services.JobsManager;
import com.lib.android.Utils.Utils;
import com.lib.android.activity.BaseActivity;
import com.lib.android.dataAccess.DatabaseManager;

public class JobCheckoutActivity extends BaseActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setViewContent();
    }

    private void setViewContent() {

        Settings setting = getSettings();
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.job_checkout);
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.customtitle);
        //new DataProcess().execute(null);
        TextView text1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.checkoutmessage);
        text1.setText("Processiong Job Cart ...");
        if(setting!=null){
            TextView text2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.checkoutheading);
            text2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Button homeButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.gohome);
            homeButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        JSONObject jobObject =encodeData(setting);
        sendDataToServer(jobObject);
        } 

    }
    private void sendDataToServer(JSONObject jobObject) {
        TextView text1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.checkoutmessage);
        text1.setText("Processiong Job Cart ...");
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000); // Timeout
                                                                                // Limit
        HttpResponse response;
        try {
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(Utils.getPostUrl());
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("orderparameters",
                    jobObject.toString()));
            Log.i("Job ORDER", jobObject.toString());
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            response = client.execute(post);
            checkResponseFromServer(response);
            ClearCart();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w("error", "connection failed");
            Toast.makeText(this, "Order not placed due to connection error",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

    private void ClearCart() {
        JobsManager.JobsCartList.clear();

    }

    private void checkResponseFromServer(HttpResponse response) {
        try {
            if (response != null) {
                InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(in));

                String line;
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line);

                }

                in.close();

                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(buffer.toString());
                Log.i("Status", jsonResponse.getString("status"));
                Log.i("Status", jsonResponse.getString("message"));
                Log.i("Status", jsonResponse.getString("debug"));
                TextView text1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.checkoutheading);
                text1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.checkoutmessage);
                if (jsonResponse.getString("status").equals("SUCC")) {
                    text.setText( Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.checkout_body1)));
                } else
                    text.setText(jsonResponse.getString("message")
                            + jsonResponse.getString("debug")); 

            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
    }


    private JSONObject encodeData(Settings setting) {
        JSONObject jobObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            JSONObject jobject = new JSONObject();
            jobject.put("name", setting.getName());
            jobject.put("email", setting.getEmail());
            jobject.put("phone", setting.getPhone());
            jobject.put("school", setting.getSchool());
            jobject.put("major", setting.getMajor());

            jobObject.put("customer", jobject);
            JSONArray jobsarray = new JSONArray();
            for (Job job : JobsManager.JobsCartList) {
                JSONObject jobEntry = new JSONObject();
                jobEntry.put("jobtitle",job.getTitle());
                jobEntry.put("qty","1");
                jobsarray.put(jobEntry);
            }
            jobObject.put("orders", jobsarray);
        } catch (JSONException ex) {

        }
        return jobObject;
    }


    private Settings getSettings() {
        SettingsDBAccess settingsDBAccess = new SettingsDBAccess(
                DatabaseManager.getInstance());

        Settings setting = settingsDBAccess.getSetting();
        if (setting==null){
                startActivityForResult((new Intent(this,SettingsActivity.class)),Utils
                        .getDefaultRequestCode());
        }
        return setting;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Settings setting = new SettingsDBAccess(
                DatabaseManager.getInstance()).getSetting();
        if(setting!=null){
            JSONObject jobObject = encodeData(setting);
            sendDataToServer(jobObject);
        }

    }
/*  private class DataProcess extends AsyncTask {
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {

        }

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
            processDataandsend();
            return null;
        }

        private void processDataandsend() {
            Settings setting = getSettings();

            if(setting!=null){
                TextView text2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.checkoutheading);
                text2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Button homeButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.gohome);
                homeButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            JSONObject jobObject =encodeData(setting);
            sendDataToServer(jobObject);

        }
    }

    } */
}
```

Comment: You could start by not performing HTTP-work on the UI-thread, that's blocking your UI until it's done - thus not showing your processing message. Use an AsyncTask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not perform HTTP-work on the UI-thread. Instead use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

In your AsyncTask you are only allowed to update the UI in two places:

```
  @Override
protected void onPreExecute() 
TextView.setText("Beginning HTTP-work..Please wait");
{
```

and

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {
TextView.setText("Done..SUCCESS!");
}
```

Use these two to update the UI before and after the HTTP-work has been done.

Answer (score 0):

Long operations must be in background. Best way to implement this on Android, use AsyncTask, for more information: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html